# Creation of sibling components in a particular order in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am working on a sample Angular 2 application in which root component has 4 sibling components.

I would like to know if it is possible to control the creation order of sibling components in root component.

Lets say root component contains "sibling1Component" , "sibling2Component", "sibling3Component" and "sibling4Component" components.

I would like the sibling components to be created in below order

"sibling2Component" , "sibling4Component" , "sibling1Component" , "sibling3Component".

Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: by creation u mean when the constructor function is called, right ?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: how the resulting html should look like? and do you create components dynamically?

Comment: components are not created dynamically .... and the sibling component tags may not be placed in the required creation order sequence

Comment: then as Dhyey said it's not possible, the compiler creates a factory using the order the components appear in the tempalte

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `constructor` is called based on when the component is called i.e the component which is to be rendered first will be initialised first.

eg:

HTML code:

```
<div class="root-comp">
    <sibling2Component></sibling2Component>
    <sibling1Component></sibling1Component>
</div>
```

In the above code `constructor` method of `sibling2Component` will be called first and then `sibling1Component` will be called. The order in `declarations` array of `NgModule` doesn't matter.

I have made a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/poLIJvSbvXNRGUsvPP4G?p=preview) to demonstrate this, where `<third-comp></third-comp>` is the first to be called although it has been added at the end of `declarations` array.

So basically this is what your HTML should look like:

```
<div class="root-comp">
    <sibling2Component></sibling2Component>
    <sibling4Component></sibling4Component>
    <sibling2Component></sibling2Component>
    <sibling3Component></sibling3Component>
</div>
```